# What does “$\prod$” mean?

Tags: notation, definition

In the following formula:
$$P_i(z)= \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(z+2^jx_i) \mod 2^k.$$

- What does "$\prod$" mean?

Comment: [Capital Pi notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_Pi_notation)

Comment: Yes product as others have stated, it's the poduct equivalent of stating that $\Sigma$ means sum.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For comparison (if you are familiar with the sigma-notation):

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i=a_0+a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n$$
 $$\prod_{i=0}^{n}a_i=a_0\times a_1\times a_2\times\dots\times a_n$$

The only difference is that you multiply instead of adding. So $$\boxed{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(z+2^jx_i)=(z+2^0x_i)\times (z+2^1x_i)\times(z+2^2x_i)\times\dots\times(z+2^{k-1}x_i)\\=(z+x_i)(z+2x_i)(z+4x_i)\times\dots\times (z+2^{k-1}x_i)}$$

The greek letter $\Sigma$, sigma, is a capital *S*, and is used to represent *sum*, similarly the greek letter $\Pi$, pi, is a capital *P*, and is used to represent *product*.

Comment: You could at least mention that Pi was chosen to represent Product.

Comment: @aml I agree, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The Product of.

So multiply together all the $z + 2^jx_i$ for each $j=0$ to $k-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol you expressed as $$\Pi$$ is known as the product of an expression

in the formula, it says (in words), "P sub i of z = "the product" when j = 0 and goes to k - 1 of z + 2 to the j separated by x sub i where the whole formula is modded by 2 to the k"

Comment: `\prod` looks better than `\Pi`, and works better with limits, especially in display mode:$$\prod_{i = 1}^n\quad\text{versus}\quad\Pi_{i = 1}^n$$It's the same with `\sum` and `\Sigma`.

Comment: thanks for the help!